# Role of binomial coefficents in nested summations in layman terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients, intuition

I has this doubt from almost two years and not getting a simple solution in layman terms. In short, the doubt is the about **relation between binomial coefficients and the nesting summation**.

Recently I started reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.08699.pdf) pre print in which authors claimed a formula and it shows relation between nesting and binomial coefficients used.

The formula given is as follows:

$$\sum\limits_{}^{(m)} n^k = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n+m-1}{m+i} \mu[k,i]$$

Let's kept aside $\mu[k,i]$. The formula is showing relation between nesting ($m$) and the corresponding binomial coefficients used $\binom{n+m-i}{m+i}$.

In simple terms, if the binomial coefficient is $\binom{x}{y}$ for nesting $m$, then if we increase one more summation i.e., $(m+1)$, the binomial coefficients become $\binom{x+1}{y+1}$. The proving technique used is mathematical induction and hence can't able to get any clue from the pre print.

Is there any **intuitive explanation to understand this**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a starter. We provide a combinatorial proof of the simplest case $k=0$. In order to do so we derive a more conventional representation of OP's stated formula and and give some additional information regarding the coefficients $\mu[k,i]$.

> We start with a more conventional representation of the formula. Following the definition of $\sum^{(m)}$ given in the paper we have for non-negative integers $m,k$ and positive integers $n$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum^{(m)}n^k=
> \begin{cases}
> \sum_{j=1}^n\sum^{(m-1)}j^k&m>0\tag{1}\\
> n^k&m=0
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain from (1)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum^{(1)}n^k&=\sum_{j_1=1}^n\sum^{(0)}j_1^k=\sum_{j_1=1}^nj_1^k=\sum_{1\leq j_1\leq n}j_1^k\\
> \sum^{(2)}n^k&=\sum_{j_2=1}^n\sum^{(1)}j_2^k=\sum_{j_2=1}^n\sum_{j_1=1}^{j_2}j_1^k=\sum_{1\leq j_1\leq j_2\leq n}j_1^k\\
> \end{align*}
>   and  conclude  for general $m>0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum^{(m)}n^k=\sum_{1\leq j_1\leq \ldots\leq j_m\leq n}j_1^k}\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> With (2) OP's formula can now be written as
>   \begin{align*}
> &\sum_{j_m=1}^{n}\sum_{j_{m-1}=1}^{j_m}\cdots\sum_{j_1=1}^{j_2}j_1^k\\
> &\qquad=\color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq j_1\leq \ldots \leq j_{m}\leq n}j_1^k=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n+m-1}{m+j}\mu[k,j]}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

Now we look in some more detail at the numbers $\mu[k,j]$.

**The numbers $\mu[k,j]$:**

> The authors of the paper introduce the numbers $\mu[k,j]$ as triangle numbers
>   $$
> \begin{array}{l|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
> k/j&0&1&2&3&4&\cdots\\
> \hline
> 0&1\\
> 1&1&1\\
> 2&1&3&2\\
> 3&1&7&12&6\\
> 4&1&15&50&60&24\\
> \,\vdots&&&\vdots\,&&&\\
> \end{array}
> $$
>   and denote them as **Saras numbers**. In fact these numbers are already known as **Worpitzky numbers** *[(see here)](http://www.luschny.de/ect/Worpitzky-Triangle.html)* and are stored as *[A028246](http://oeis.org/A028246)* in OEIS.org. They can be represented via *[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)* $k\brace j$ and OPs formula (3) becomes
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq j_1\leq \ldots\leq  j_m\leq n}j_1^k=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n+m-1}{m+j}j!{{k+1}\brace{j+1}}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

**The special case $k=0$:**

> Setting $k=0$ in (4) we have
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{1\leq j_1\leq \ldots \leq j_m\leq n}1=\binom{n+m-1}{m}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> The left-hand side of (5) can be interpreted as follows. We count the number of occurrences of $1\leq j_1\leq \ldots \leq j_m\leq n$ . There is a one-to-one correspondence between these and the $(m+1)$-tupel
>   \begin{align*}
> (n-j_{m},j_m-j_{m-1},\ldots,j_1-1)
> \end{align*}
>   whose entries sum up to $n-1$. This can be counted by arranging $n-1$ balls and $m$ dividers between bins in a row which can be done in $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$ ways. This is the right-hand side of (5).

Comment: Does any other proof exist for other values of k?

Comment: I was busy when bounty, that's why the delay happened. But please update the answer whenever possible and I will also try in between. If needs bounty, I will again give it.

Comment: @Hindu: Don't worry about  the bounty. I don't have  a combinatorial  answer at hand. But I think an algebraic proof of (4) could be within reach.

Comment: I am not sure this helps and probably you already observed this yourself but from your initial expressions (before $\mu$) it easily follows that$$\sum^{(m)}n^k=\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{n+m-1-j}{m-1}j^k$$

Comment: I believe one can approach the general case by combining the above with$$\sum_\ell{k\brace\ell}\ell!\binom j\ell=j^k$$which has an easy combinatorial proof (maps $k\to j$ = (surjections $k\twoheadrightarrow\ell$, permutations $\ell\approx\ell$, $\ell$-element subsets of $j$))